# How can hide html LI control in code behind?

Tags: c#, html

I tried to hide a `<li>` but it's not working:

```
<li runat="server" id="theLi">This is test</li>
```

**C# code:**

```
theLi.Visible = false;
```

Error **

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Do you mean ```theLi.Visible = false``` ? Or you want to hide the div holding the element?   theDiv.Visible = false  .The element needs to be within the ```</div>``` Also make sure there is no other css overriding theLi properties.

Comment: @David i corrected it.

Comment: @w4nn48cy83r yes its theLi.Visible = false

Comment: Are you sure this code-behind variable controls this control?  Is anything else changing the visibility?  Where in the page lifecycle is this one line of code executing and what else is happening in that lifecycle?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: How to: Access Server Controls by ID
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/y81z8326(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

You are probably trying to access a control which is inside named container.

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = 
            FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once you call this function, you can use the visibility status

```
var ctrl = FindControlRecursive(this, "theLi");
if (ctrl !=null) {
   ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```